# Cоставить регулярное выражение: заменить вхождение символов в строке

Tags: jquery, регулярные-выражения, javascript

И так, у меня есть какая то СТРОКОВАЯ переменная под названием `func`, в которой сводится тело какой то функции. Для примера возьмем ее как константу. Мне надо из этой строковой переменной заменить все вхождения `$(this)` на `self` как это делать я уже понял, но какое надо составить регулярное выражение?  
Вот это же на [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/igolka97/sxYMs/)

```
var func = "function(){alert($(this).text());}";
while(func.search("/\$(this)/")!= -1){
func = func.replace('/\$(this)/', "self");
alert(func);
}
```

Comment: Отформатируйте правильно вопрос. Подсказка: под полем ввода есть ПРЕДПРОСМОТР!

Comment: @VladD спасибо добавьте ваш отмет в ответы чтобы я закрыл вопрос

Comment: @igolka97: готово :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте [так](http://jsfiddle.net/sxYMs/1/):

```
func = func.replace(/\$\(this\)/g, "self");
```

Регулярные выражения пишутся в js без кавычек, а с ключом `g` не нужен и цикл.